# Setting up port forwarding for a game with two routers

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have two routers (router and modem). One is an Xfinity one then the second is the Linksys Velop system that is a mesh network of multiple nodes. I am trying to set up port forwarding to set up a server. I have access to both websites for the configuration of the routers. So the Xfinity router has one device connected to it, the main Linksys node. Then that Linksys node is connected via ethernet to my laptop. The thing I am confused about is how to set up the port forward to go directly to my laptop.

I did the 'ipconfig' command and my ipv4 address was 10.226.1.35. Then, for some reason, I can access the settings of the Linksys router via two IP addresses. One is 10.0.0.94 and the other is 10.226.1.1. I have been trying this for hours and I still cannot figure it out. Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you kindly.

[Router 2 Port Forward Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeqpH.png)

[Router 1 Port Forward Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc5ST.png)

[CanYouSeeMe.org Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF0HI.png)

Answer (score 1):

As I get it, you have following setup:

```
(internet)-[router1]-[router2]-{laptop}
```

Router has two IPs, external and internal (unless it's bridge).
Now you have to setup port forwarding (for example port 8080)

- [router1]: port 8080 forward to external ip of router2 (I think it's 10.0.0.94 in your case
- [router2]: port 8080 forward to your laptop 10.226.1.35

So packet from game server will be chain routed to your laptop.

Comment: Okay I set that up but when I tried to check if the port was open on one of those websites, it said it was closed. I believe I used https://www.canyouseeme.org/   The game is Minecraft if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Router 1 IP - `10.0.0.1`
Router 2 IP - `10.0.0.94`(assigned by Router 1) and `10.226.1.1`(gateway IP)
Your IP - `10.226.1.35`
Router 2 has 2 IPs because one IP is given by the first router. The second IP is necessary to act as an Access Point.
1. Open `10.0.0.1`
2. Do a port forward to IP `10.0.0.94`
3. Open `10.0.0.94`
4. Do a port forward to ```10.226.1.35``
Now, you are good to go. Only forward the port required by the game for better security. Also confirm that your firewall does not block that port.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry if this seems dumb but when I check if the port is open, do I use my public IP or the IP of my computer?